# QT QmlMap PolyLine not updated properly when underlying model changes

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I'm trying to connect several GeoCoordinates with a polyline in my map. The Coordinates are stored in an model (QAbstractListModel) class, where I can modify (remove and add) the Coords in C++.

Simply displaying markers for every coordinate works fine, but when I connect them with a Polyline and delete some existing coordinates from my model, the Polyline does not get updated.

**map.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Item {
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true

    id: mainWindow

    Map { //our map
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: map
        plugin: mapPlugin
        zoomLevel: 14
        focus: true

        Plugin {
            id: mapPlugin
            name: "osm"
        }

        MapItemView {
            model: markerModel
            delegate: mapcomponent
        }

        MapItemView {
            model: markerModel
            delegate: MapPolyline {
                antialiasing: true
                line.color: "darkBlue"
                line.width: 3
                path: pathRole
            }
        }

        Component {
            id: mapcomponent
            MapQuickItem{
                id: marker
                coordinate: positionRole
                sourceItem: Image{
                    id: markerimage
                    width: 20
                    height: 30
                    source: "qrc:/marker.png"
                }
                anchorPoint.x: markerimage.width / 2
                anchorPoint.y: markerimage.height
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            onClicked: {
                var coord = parent.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
                markerModel.addMarker(coord)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**markermodel.h** which stores the coordinates

```cpp
class MarkerModel : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QAbstractListModel::QAbstractListModel;
    enum MarkerRoles{positionRole = Qt::UserRole, pathRole};

    Q_INVOKABLE void addMarker(const QGeoCoordinate &coordinate) {
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
        m_coordinates.append(coordinate);
        endInsertRows();
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override {
        Q_UNUSED(parent)
        return m_coordinates.count();
    }

    bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) override {
        if(row + count > m_coordinates.count() || row < 0)
            return false;

        beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row+count-1);
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            m_coordinates.removeAt(row + i);
        endRemoveRows();

        return true;
    }

    bool removeRow(int row, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) {
        return removeRows(row, 1, parent);
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override {
        if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_coordinates.count())
            return QVariant();
        if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
            return QVariant::fromValue(index.row());
        if(role == MarkerModel::positionRole)
            return QVariant::fromValue(m_coordinates[index.row()]);        
        if(role == MarkerModel::pathRole) {
            QVariantList coordlist;
            for(auto &geocoord : m_coordinates)
                coordlist << QVariant::fromValue(geocoord);

            return coordlist;
        }

        return QVariant();
    }

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const {
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
        roles[positionRole] = "positionRole";
        roles[pathRole] = "pathRole";
        return roles;
    }

private:
    QList<QGeoCoordinate> m_coordinates;
};
```

A gif showing my problem:

[image]

Did I miss something when deleting rows in my model? Is there a way to force qml to render the polyline with completly new data from the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they indicate your code has a logic error, in my answer I will show the implementation since [@GrecKo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2788674/grecko) already explained the correct logic:

**markermodel.h**

```
#ifndef MARKERMODEL_H
#define MARKERMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QGeoCoordinate>

class MarkerModel : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList path READ path NOTIFY pathChanged)
public:
    enum MarkerRoles{positionRole = Qt::UserRole, pathRole};
    MarkerModel(QObject *parent=nullptr): QAbstractListModel(parent)
    {
        connect(this, &QAbstractListModel::rowsInserted, this, &MarkerModel::pathChanged);
        connect(this, &QAbstractListModel::rowsRemoved, this, &MarkerModel::pathChanged);
        connect(this, &QAbstractListModel::dataChanged, this, &MarkerModel::pathChanged);
        connect(this, &QAbstractListModel::modelReset, this, &MarkerModel::pathChanged);
        connect(this, &QAbstractListModel::rowsMoved, this, &MarkerModel::pathChanged);
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void addMarker(const QGeoCoordinate &coordinate) {
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
        m_coordinates.append(coordinate);
        endInsertRows();
    }
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override {
        if(parent.isValid()) return 0;
        return m_coordinates.count();
    }
    bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) override {
        if(row + count > m_coordinates.count() || row < 0)
            return false;
        beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row+count-1);
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            m_coordinates.removeAt(row + i);
        endRemoveRows();
        return true;
    }

    bool removeRow(int row, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) {
        return removeRows(row, 1, parent);
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override {
        if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_coordinates.count())
            return QVariant();
        if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
            return QVariant::fromValue(index.row());
        else if(role == MarkerModel::positionRole)
            return QVariant::fromValue(m_coordinates[index.row()]);
        return QVariant();
    }
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override{
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
        roles[positionRole] = "positionRole";
        return roles;
    }
    QVariantList path() const{
        QVariantList path;
        for(const QGeoCoordinate & coord: m_coordinates){
            path << QVariant::fromValue(coord);
        }
        return path;
    }
signals:
    void pathChanged();
private:
    QList<QGeoCoordinate> m_coordinates;
};

#endif // MARKERMODEL_H
```

***.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Item {    
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true

    id: mainWindow

    Map { //our map
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: map
        plugin: mapPlugin
        zoomLevel: 14
        focus: true

        Plugin {
            id: mapPlugin
            name: "osm"
        }

        MapItemView {
            model: markerModel
            delegate: mapcomponent
        }

        MapPolyline{
            antialiasing: true
            line.color: "darkBlue"
            line.width: 3
            path: markerModel.path
        }

        Component {
            id: mapcomponent
            MapQuickItem{
                id: marker
                coordinate: positionRole
                sourceItem: Image{
                    id: markerimage
                    width: 20
                    height: 30
                    source: "qrc:/marker.png"
                }
                anchorPoint.x: markerimage.width / 2
                anchorPoint.y: markerimage.height
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            onClicked: {
                var coord = parent.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
                markerModel.addMarker(coord)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the implementation, that helped me indeed and everything works now!

Comment: I have tried to get this answer to work but the MapPolyline does not update. Reading the Qt documentation it states that a MapPolyline path cannot be directly updated, you have to copy it out alter it then copy it back in again. Does the line path: markerModel.path really work?

Comment: @CitizenFish I have tested my solution and it worked on the date I published (Even the OP accepts it which implies that at least it worked for him), I will check it again later. On the other hand, you should always indicate the characteristics of your environment: Qt version and OS. On the other hand if you have a problem and the solutions proposed in another question do not work for you (as this case seems to be) then we invite you to create a new question providing an MRE to see where the cause of the problem is (maybe somewhere in your code there is another problem)

Comment: It is probably down to environment. I am using Qt 5.14 and registering the model with    qmlRegisterType<MarkerModel>("MarkerModel", 1, 0, "MarkerModel"); I wonder if that makes a difference

Answer (score 2):

Having a `pathRole` doesn't make much sense here. This role is the same for all the rows of your model. 
You display n `MapPolyline` where n is the number of coordinates, you only need one for your entire model.

I would advise you to remove the `pathRole` and just expose a `path` property in your model, and emit its notify signal in `addMarker` and `removeRows`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes absolutely sense!